# Model deforming clipping and falling through clothing

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I started trying to do a walk animation, and I added some clothes to the character. But, for some reason, the player falls through the clothing. I'm admittedly very new to cloth physics, and animation in general so it's probably something simple. But I've been at this for hours and can't figure it out.

I haven't even gotten to the actual animation part. When I set the animation to any frame other than 1 the model starts deforming and ballooning through the clothing.

[image]

[Here is the HDR image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XMVzcOVKQLF272cLtGULNTFP4IgeuPG1/view?usp=sharing)

Here is my model

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this issue was to apply a collision modifier to the model.

Step 1.) Go to Modifier Properties -> Add Modifier -> collision modifier -> Right-click

Step 2.) Make sure your model doesn't intersect the clothing or whatever secondary object you have. It will cause issues with the solver.

Then apply the collision modifier. The clothing needs to have a collision modifier as well.

This solves that issue, but the model and clothing fall through the floor now. So this is not a complete solution. But that's a different problem for a different question.